# Set default field value in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

How can I set the default value of a date field in Acumatica to show as today?  The field I am looking at is the Start Date field on the task entry screen CR306020.

Using version 5.00.2908

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form you can also use PXDefaultAttribute on your field using business date like so:

```
[PXDate]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "From Date")]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
public virtual DateTime? FromDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FieldDefaulting in graph. For example

```
public class CRTaskMaintExt: PXGraphExtension<CRTaskMaint>
{    
 protected virtual void DiscountDetail_StartDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender,    PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
            {
                SO.DiscountDetail row = e.Row as SO.DiscountDetail;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    e.NewValue = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am a relatively basic user but can work with Customisations and Editing Attributes - not too sure how I should go about inserting this code?

Comment: I recommend you to read manual T100 in Acumatica university, they described this process